# Which tenant owns the application created by teams fx toolkit?

Tags: app-id, teams-toolkit, app-secret

I've created an azure bot and application using teams toolkit, but it doesn't seem to be owned by the tenant I'm in. I want to change the password of this application, how do I find the owner of this application to change the secret?

**Azure Bot Config** [image: Azure Bot Config]

**resources**
[image: resources]

**enterprise application page** [image: enterprise application page]

Answer (score 0):

When using Teams Toolkit, you will login 2 accounts:

1. Azure account under your Azure subscription's tenant
2. M365 account under your M365 tenant

The AAD app created for your Azure Bot Registration is under your M365 tenant. So you need to find the AAD app there.

If there're multiple similar AAD application under your M365 tenant, you can find the AAD app client id in `.fx/configs/states/state.{env}.json`. It's stored in the `botId` field under the `fx-resource-bot` property:

```
    "fx-resource-bot": {
        "botId": "...",
```